# Focus of Expansion

Tags: ios, image-processing, opencv, opticalflow

I had previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553861/collision-avoidance-using-opencv-on-ipad) but not received any response for it. Here I look to narrow it down much further, in a hope for an answer.

How to calculate Focus of Expansion, after deriving the optical flow from OpenCV?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your questions are to broad and vague to be answered. You did start to use optical flow, without knowing why yo need it. No one here seem to know how to do it, and it's a good chance that it's either a nonsense, either a too complicated thing. You should focus on simple things, which you can understand well, and build on them, little by little. Copying code from the internet will not help you.

Comment: @vasile - That's a little harsh, and you really shouldn't take that tone with someone who is genuinely trying to ask good questions. While technically challenging, the linked question shows research effort and could be answered here by the right person. Likewise, this is a specific, answerable question as well.

Comment: I think you're right, @BradLarson . I will try to offer more support and less critics. Thanks for your input.

Comment: This is not a good way of calculating the focus of expansion but it would be easy to implement and might (I have never tried this) work ok.  The function cv::FindHomography will give you the 3x3 matrix that best describes the point to point matches you find with optical flow.  It seems to me that for some kinds of optical flow the optimal homography would be centered at the focus of expansion.  If that is true you could try taking the x and y translation components of the homography and use them ( x is hom(0,2) y is hom(1,2)).  I hope you get a better answer than that

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume a static scene with a moving camera, where all optical-flow is induced by the camera motion. There is *no camera rotation*, only (3D) translation.
In this case the FOE - *focus of expansion* - is the intersection point of *all* the pixel flows.

You can use least-squares to find the FoE as the null-space of the over-determined matrix whose rows are the lines defined by the motion vectors. RANSAC may be a more robust approach.

In the case of lateral motion the FoE will be at infinity, in the case of forward motion it will be a point within the image.

In the more general case, the FoE is the epipole which can be found once you have estimated the Fundamental matrix.

Comment: Hi Adi, sorry for such a delayed response. I have understood the FoE concept. My problem is I'm not able to do this in code. Is there any library or sample app which enables/demonstrates this? Does OpenCV enable us to determine FoE?

Comment: OpenCV allows you to find the fundamental matrix and the epipoles.